# Join query returns different results

Tags: sql, join

Please help...

I'm trying to get traffic data from my site www.mentallica.co.il using SQL
The problem is that my left join query returns different value when I'm using two or more.

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM([TrafficDay].UniqueTraffic), 0) AS TrafficDay,
       [Topics].topicNumber
FROM [Topics]
LEFT JOIN [Traffic] AS TrafficDay
    ON ([TrafficDay].Date >= '10/16/2013'
        AND [TrafficDay].Date <= '10/16/2013')
   AND [TrafficDay].TopicNumber = [Topics].TopicNumber
GROUP BY [Topics].TopicNumber
```

Will return a `TrafficDay` real value

And the problem query is

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM([TrafficDay].UniqueTraffic), 0) AS TrafficDay,
       ISNULL(SUM([TrafficWeek].UniqueTraffic), 0) AS TrafficWeek,
       [Topics].topicNumber
FROM [Topics] 
LEFT JOIN [Traffic] AS TrafficDay
    ON ([TrafficDay].Date >= '10/16/2013'
   AND [TrafficDay].Date <= '10/16/2013')
   AND [TrafficDay].TopicNumber = [Topics].TopicNumber
LEFT JOIN [Traffic] AS TrafficWeek
    ON ([TrafficWeek].Date > '10/09/2013'
        AND [TrafficWeek].Date < '10/16/2013')
   AND [TrafficWeek].TopicNumber = [Topics].TopicNumber
GROUP BY [Topics].TopicNumber
```

This will return different (much bigger) value for `TrafficDay`

Why is that ?
How can I get the real values for `TrafficDay` and `TrafficWeek`?

Any solution would be great!
How do i join the same table based on other table values...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried temporarily creating a new view by right clicking on any view and selecting 'New View' then copy and paste your query into the box below. From there you will have somewhat of an Access view of your query and may be able to better visualize and change your joins ie the arrows between tables. Just a suggestion. Works for me sometimes. Good luck.

Comment: I just did that, it has visualized my join but still i did not manage to get the right values after using 2 or more joint's